# jQuery: iterate over elements and copy an attribute's value to a data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide elements from screenreaders using `aria-hidden="true"` when I display a dialog box. When the dialog box is un-displayed, I have to remove the `aria-hidden` again.

In case there are elements that do already have an `aria-hidden` value set, I want to cache their original state in a data attribute, so I can set it back to the original value again when un-displaying the dialog box.

```
$('body > :not(#dialog)').each ->
  $el = $(@)
  $el.data('dialog-aria-hidden', $el.attr('aria-hidden')) # Store original value
  $el.attr('aria-hidden', true) # Set new value
```

I don't like to have to create a temporary `$el` element. Is there a quicker way to do this? Something like this maybe?

```
$('body > :not(#dialog)').data('dialog-aria-hidden', attr('aria-hidden')).attr('aria-hidden', true)
```

Comment: If your code is working fine and objective of this question is to seek improvements, you should try [CodeReviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: @Satpal Why did you delete your answer? It looks good to me.